# Sort multidimension array in php by more than two fields

Tags: php

I want to sort array by two fields. I mean to say I have an array like :-

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img1.png
        [count] => 69
        [img] => accessoire-sets_1.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc2
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 73
        [img] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc45
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img122.png
        [count] => 15
        [img] => tomahawk-kopen_1.png
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => zyz
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img22.png
        [count] => 168
        [img] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => lmn
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img1222.png
        [count] => 10
        [img] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => qqq
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img1222.png
        [count] => 70
        [img] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => dsa
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img1112.png
        [count] => 43
        [img] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => wer
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img172.png
        [count] => 228
        [img] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => hhh
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img126.png
        [count] => 36
        [img] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => rrrt
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 51
        [img] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => yyy
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 22
        [img] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [name] => cxz
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 41
        [img] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [name] => tre
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 32
        [img] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [name] => fds
        [url] => http://127.0.0.1/abc/img12.png
        [count] => 10
        [img] => 
    )

    )
```

array WITHOUT images (field "img" )should always be placed underneath array WITH images. After this there will be sorted on the amount of products (field count) in the array.

Means I have to show sort array first on the basis of img then count.

I am using

```
usort( $childLinkCats, 'sortempty' );`

function sortempty( $a, $b ) {
    return empty( $a['img'] );
}
```

it will show array with image value above the one who contains null value.

and to sort through count Im using

```
usort($childLinkCats, "_sortByCount");
function _sortByCount($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['count'], $b['count']);
}
```

It will short by count

But I am facing problem that only 1 working is working at a time, but I have to use both, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that calls both comparison functions:

```
usort($childLinkCats, function($a, $b) {
    if (empty($a['img']) == empty($b['img'])) {
        return _sortByCount($a, $b);
    } else {
        return sortempty($a, $b);
    }
});
```

You need to ensure that `_sortByCount` and `sortempty` return proper values. Comparison functions must return -1, 0, or 1, not true or false.

Comment: The comparison function should return < 0, 0 or > 0, you are just returning a boolean.

Comment: It will short only by image empty value

Comment: I want to use both sorting, how will i get required result.

Comment: Its only sorted by count. First I want to show array with img value and also sorted by count then it will show array with img value as null and this also sorted by count. I think requirement will be clear

Comment: I forgot to use `['img']` to get the images.